# How can I figure out why MongoDB NodeJS driver isn't returning results for valid queries for a single collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB v3.2.7 for NodeJS v10.16.0.  I created a MongoRepository base class that we've been using for a few years in Production.  Sometimes in Development, I find quirky behavior where it won't return any results for a specific collection.  I used to think this was because I wasn't closing the client between queries.  I'm not so sure, now.

I'm running the code through an Express server, and a half dozen other calls are working just fine.  Then I get this query & projection and no results (even though these work in the command line and in Robo 3T):

> Query =
>   {"pin":"xxxxxx","documentId":"5c584a76a690bb28ff8021cb","page":1}, 
>   Projection = {"_class":0,"documentId":0,"pin":0,"base64":0} data = []

I haven't any idea how to start debugging this.  Help?

Here's the base class code:

```
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import 'dotenv/config';

const url = process.env...; // elided to hide our secrets
const dbname = process.env...; // elided to hide our secrets

class MongoRepository
{
    /**
     * Returns the database using the configuration
     */
    async getDatabase()
    {
        if (!MongoRepository.client)
        {
            MongoRepository.client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

            await MongoRepository.client.connect();

            if (!MongoRepository.client || !MongoRepository.client.db(dbname))
            {
                throw new Error(`Unable to connect to Mongo with URL '${url}'`);
            }
        }

        return MongoRepository.client.db(dbname);
    }

    /**
     * Override this method in children to add any special query filter for a collection.
     * @param {*} query query object to modify
     */
    addRepositoryFilter(query) {
        return query;
    }

    /**
     * Generic find method that takes a query and a projection.
     *
     * @param {*} query Lookup parameters
     * @param {*} projection Fields to return or not return from the search
     *
     */
    async find(query, projection = {})
    {
        query = this.addRepositoryFilter(query);

        let db = await this.getDatabase();

        return await db.collection(this.CollectionName).find(query).project(projection).toArray();
    }
}

export default MongoRepository;
```

Here's the subclass that's not getting results:

```
import MongoRepository from "./MongoRepository";

class ViewerPageRepository extends MongoRepository
{
    get CollectionName()
    {
        return 'viewerPage';
    }

    async findByPinDocumentIdPage(pin, documentId, page, projection)
    {
        documentId = this.objectIdToString(documentId);

        let query = {
            pin: pin,
            documentId: documentId,
            page: page
        };

        console.log(`Query = ${JSON.stringify(query)}, Projection = ${JSON.stringify(projection)}`);

        return await this.find(query, projection);
    }
}

export default ViewerPageRepository;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after thinking to check the type of `documentId` in my query.  It is stored as a hex string in the collection I am querying.  I didn't include the `objectIdToString` function in my code, but it calls `valueOf` on the `documentId` if it's an `ObjectId` instance.  This should have converted it to a string, but for some reason I was getting back another `ObjectId` instance (maybe the same instance I had called `valueOf` on - I didn't check).  So, this appears to have been caused by a bug in the MongoDB driver's `ObjectId::valueOf` method.  I will report the issue.